# Store uploaded file data into array

Tags: php, codeigniter, multifile-uploader, dropzone.js

I have the following situation:
I need to upload 3 files at once, when the user clicks to do so. There's the code I have in my view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('uploads/do_upload', 'class="dropzone", id="dropzone-prod", data-nextFormExecDropzone="#dropzone-promo"');?>
   <div class="fallback">
     <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
   </div>
</form>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('uploads/do_upload', 'class="dropzone", id="dropzone-promo", data-nextFormExecDropzone="#dropzone-plan"');?>
   <div class="fallback">
     <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
   </div>
</form>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('uploads/do_upload', 'class="dropzone", id="dropzone-plan"');?>
   <div class="fallback">
     <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
   </div>
</form>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <button id="processQueue"  class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Start Upload</button>
</div>
```

When the user clicks in the button, I have a javascript code that sends each form the order I want it to. 
In my controller, I have the following method (do_upload()):

```
function do_upload() {
    //$filePath = $this->config->item('base_current_upload_url');
    $filePath = APPPATH.'UPLOADS/';
    $filePathAfterUploaded = $this->config->item('base_uploaded_url');

    $config['upload_path'] = $filePath;
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 100;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //$this->load->library('csvreader');
    //$filePathAfterUploaded = $this->config->item('base_uploaded_url');
    //print_r($filePath); die();
    $basefilepath = APPPATH.'UPLOADS/';
    $this->load->model('uploads_m');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        print_r($error);
    }
    else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        print_r($data); die();
    }
```

}

**PROBLEM:**

I need the 3 files to be uploaded. If only one is missing I can't proceed.
This way I'm doing, the function do_upload is being called during the upload of each file, so I need to find a way to identify that the 3 files were uploaded. (After that, I'll use mysql 'load data infile' to load data from these files into some tables, but I can only do this if the three were uploaded.
Can you help me finding a way to handle this situation?

The structure of the $data everytime do_uplaod is called is this:

```
Array
(
[upload_data] => Array
    (
        [file_name] => PROMOWEB111120131.txt
        [file_type] => text/plain
        [file_path] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/integration/www/application/UPLOADS/
        [full_path] => C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9/data/localweb/projects/integration/www/application/UPLOADS/PROMOWEB111120131.txt
        [raw_name] => PROMOWEB111120131
        [orig_name] => PROMOWEB11112013.txt
        [client_name] => PROMOWEB11112013.txt
        [file_ext] => .txt
        [file_size] => 2.67
        [is_image] => 
        [image_width] => 
        [image_height] => 
        [image_type] => 
        [image_size_str] => 
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `do_upload` is a standalone function, then introduce a static variable that counts the number of calls.

```
function do_upload () {
    static $count = 0;
    // The rest of your function goes here
    if (no_errors_occurred) {
        static::$count++;
    }
    if ($count == 3) {
        // This function has been called 3 times; trigger something here
    }
}
```

Better yet, if it's in a class...

```
class MyClass {
    protected static $data = array ();

    // Other functions and properties

    public function do_upload () {
        // The rest of your function
        if (no_errors_occurred) {
            static::$data[] = array (
                'upload_data' => array (
                    'file_name' => ...,
                    // Populate the data array
                )
            );
        }
        $this->do_mysql_load_data_infile();
    }

    protected function do_mysql_load_data_infile () {
        if (count(static::$data) != 3) {
            return false;
        }
        // Do MySQL load data infile
        // Get information about file uploads by accessing the static::$data array
        foreach (static::$data as $file) {
            echo $file['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but how would I identify the name of the file in this do_mysql_load_data_infile ?

Comment: See my class example above. Instead of just storing the count, store the data in an array and check the length of the array.